# SQL - Incorrect syntax near ";"

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have an written a recursive SQL query which returns some int values.
The SQL query looks like below:

```
;WITH GroupHIERARCHY(ID)  
    AS  (  SELECT ID   
    FROM tFirstTable te  
    WHERE te.LevelID <> 0   
    AND GroupID =-1
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT t.ElementID  
    FROM tFirstTable AS t, tSecondTable,GroupHIERARCHY  
    WHERE t.TypeID=tSecondTable.TypeID  
    AND GroupHIERARCHY.ID= t.GroupID)

    SELECT ID FROM GroupHIERARCHY
```

This would return some integer values. (Works fine)
What I want to do is that I want to write a query like below:

```
Select * from tExampleTable 
WHERE FirstParameter IN (IntegerValuesHere) OR SecondParameter IN (IntegerValuesHere)
```

Where, `IntegerValuesHere` are the values I get from the recursive query.

The query now would look like:

```
Select * FROM tExampleTable 
    WHERE FirstParameter IN (
        ;WITH GroupHIERARCHY(ID)  
        AS  (  SELECT ID   
        FROM tFirstTable te  
        WHERE te.LevelID <> 0   
        AND GroupID =-1
        UNION ALL  
        SELECT t.ElementID  
        FROM tFirstTable AS t, tSecondTable,GroupHIERARCHY  
        WHERE t.TypeID=tSecondTable.TypeID  
        AND GroupHIERARCHY.ID= t.GroupID)

        SELECT ID FROM GroupHIERARCHY
        ) 

    OR SecondParameter IN (
        ;WITH GroupHIERARCHY(ID)  
        AS  (  SELECT ID   
        FROM tFirstTable te  
        WHERE te.LevelID <> 0   
        AND GroupID =-1
        UNION ALL  
        SELECT t.ElementID  
        FROM tFirstTable AS t, tSecondTable,GroupHIERARCHY  
        WHERE t.TypeID=tSecondTable.TypeID  
        AND GroupHIERARCHY.ID= t.GroupID)

        SELECT ID FROM GroupHIERARCHY
    )
```

But, I get an error which says that:

> Incorrect syntax near ';'
>   and 
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'

First, for the `;` in front of `WITH`.
Second, for the `)` before `OR`.
What am I missing?

Comment: Simply remove the ; before WITH, both of them.

Comment: @jarlh That does not solve the issue.

Comment: @jarlh After removing I get an error saying near WITH expecting select.

Comment: Well, it's ANSI SQL like that... But why don't you declare the cte's first of all?

Comment: @jarlh Because this CTE is inside another CTE, so there is already another one declared.

Comment: The keyword to introduce a CTE is `WITH`. It's **not** `;WITH`. The `;` needs to go at the **end** of the _statement_. But in this case it wouldn't help, because SQL Server does not allow to use a CTE in a sub-query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot nest a `CTE` like you are trying to do. You can use it like this:

```
;WITH GroupHIERARCHY(ID)  
    AS  (  SELECT ID   
    FROM tFirstTable te  
    WHERE te.LevelID <> 0   
    AND GroupID =-1
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT t.ElementID  
    FROM tFirstTable AS t, tSecondTable,GroupHIERARCHY  
    WHERE t.TypeID=tSecondTable.TypeID  
    AND GroupHIERARCHY.ID= t.GroupID)    
Select * 
from tExampleTable 
WHERE FirstParameter IN (SELECT ID FROM GroupHIERARCHY) OR 
      SecondParameter IN (SELECT ID FROM GroupHIERARCHY)
```

Comment: This CTE is inside another CTE, what should I do in this case?

Comment: @eg16 You can simply nest them placing the one after the other, like: `;With FirstCTE AS (), SecondCTE AS ( SELECT * FROM FirstCTE JOIN .. ) ...`

Answer (score 0):

use data from different cte like this.

```
;WITH GroupHIERARCHY(ID)  
AS  (  

    SELECT ID   
    FROM tFirstTable te  
    WHERE te.LevelID <> 0   
    AND GroupID =-1
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT t.ElementID  
    FROM tFirstTable AS t, tSecondTable,GroupHIERARCHY  
    WHERE t.TypeID=tSecondTable.TypeID  
    AND GroupHIERARCHY.ID= t.GroupID
),
GroupHIERARCHY1(ID)  
AS  (  

    SELECT ID   
    FROM tFirstTable te  
    WHERE te.LevelID <> 0   
    AND GroupID =-1
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT t.ElementID  
    FROM tFirstTable AS t, tSecondTable,GroupHIERARCHY  
    WHERE t.TypeID=tSecondTable.TypeID  
    AND GroupHIERARCHY.ID= t.GroupID

)


SELECT ID FROM GroupHIERARCHY
Select * FROM tExampleTable 
WHERE FirstParameter IN (
select Id from GroupHIERARCHY
) 

OR SecondParameter IN (


SELECT ID FROM GroupHIERARCHY1
)
```